# Disable zooming for touch devices in bootstrap framework

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, zooming

I am using ***twitter bootstrap*** framework. I want to disable zooming in touch devices. I have already used

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

this. Without bootstrap framework and i can prevent zooming in touch devices, but with framework i'm not. So is there any workarounds to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a live demo? What platforms have you tested on? Does removing Bootstrap's CSS fix the issue?

Comment: You've probably multiple viewport meta tags in your markup...

Comment: @ Damian Frizzi: You are right ...there are two meta tags which is killing the functionality...thanks

Comment: Do you have and iframes on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys thanks for the answers. Actually it was my silly mistake. I had a multiple meta's in the page and it was causing the problem. Below code should work for all.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 15):

Write Following code that will disable the mobile zoom disable andy also disable for focus on the any input type

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

Answer (score 8):

If you look at Bootstrap documentation, they have said that in order to disable zooming, you must include the following meta tag between opened and closed head tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Typo in the notice?

Comment: how can i do it on asp. content page ? can i do it in code behind like Page.MetaKeywords ?

Answer (score 1):

As other guys mentioned and also you can find in Bootstrap documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile here is the solution

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```